# Passing GTM Data Layer to Analytics in Late JS Call

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've researched over Google, but all I've been able to find are explanations of GTM's built in event tracker and passing variables to Analytics in that way.

What I'm looking for is a custom Data Layer push to GTM that is then pulled into Google Analytics. I append my stuff to the dataLayer using .push and I can see that my event is firing.

However, this definitely happens after GTM's  has been called. I know that because it is called within a JavaScript function.

Is there anything special I need to do to make dataLayer.push work correctly knowing that my dataLayer.push appears after GTM's  loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, figured it out right after I posted this after spending 2 hours researching.

When dataLayer changes a synchronous push to GTM is made. You can call GTM's script at the top of the page and then modify dataLayer throughout the page and know that it is being updated.

More information can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v3/reference/com/google/tagmanager/DataLayer